# How to Parse a String to Double

Tags: c#, parsing, double

Here is my string

```
  20.0e-6
```

I'm parsing it like

```
String Ans=Double.Parse("20.0e-6")
```

Now i'm getting the result like  `2E-05`
But the required output should be like
            `0.00002`

How to get this?

Comment: yeah.... you are correct. But i need a string `0.00002` and not `2E-05`

Comment: Is that legal C#... or is it VB?

Comment: Why isn't it? String can be capitalised, and variable names can be also.

Comment: @Miguel: Thanks, forgot string and String are the same in C#.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with parsing a string to double, but with converting a double to string.

Answer (score 10):

The result of `Double.Parse` is a `Double`, not a string. You need to output a string from the double, using `ToString`.

You should also use an overload of [`Double.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4d09hy3.aspx) that has a [`NumberStyles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx) parameter. Using the `Float` value allows exponent notation:

```
string Ans=Double.Parse("20.0e-6", NumberStyles.Float).ToString("0.#####");
```

If you don't want to risk exceptions (`InvlidCastException` for example), you can use `TryParse`:

```
Double res;
if (Double.TryParse("20.0e-6", NumberStyles.Float, 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ,res))
{
  string Ans = res.ToString("0.#####");
}
```

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'string'`.
String Ans=Double.Parse("20.0e-6", NumberStyles.Float).ToString() gives the same result

Comment: I would recommend using the TryParse method on Double instead (best practice and all).

Comment: @Pramodh - Of course. You are trying to convert a string to a Double, then assign the result back to a string. As for the error with `ToString` - you need to provide a format string for it to convert properly. Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same number, but if you want to modify the output of the string, use a formatter on your `ToString()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

So

```
String Ans=Double.Parse("20.0e-6").ToString("0.0####")
```

Comment: Yeah it'll definitely crash. In reality you're best off using TryParse and applying String.Format("{0:0.0####", myDouble). I just wanted to illustrate the use of ToString to format the number.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the result you want is to use `String.Format` as follow:

```
double x = 20.0e-6;

string y = string.Format("{0:0.######}",x);

Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Given your example, this outputs the value `0.00002`

**EDIT**

I've just realised that this is actually the opposite of your question so in the aim of keeping the answer useful i'll add the following:

Given a string, you can parse as double and then apply the same logic as above. Probably not the most elegant solution however it offers another way to get the result you want.

```
string x = "20.0e-6";

var y = double.Parse(p);

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.######}",y));
```

Comment: What if my source string has a typo in it?? E.g. 20.0f-06 .....  I would always recommend using `double.TryParse` ....

Comment: agreed. I was keeping it simple and assuming the coder already follows good practices.